# Finding $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Compute  $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}$$ It seems pretty obvious, but I have tried Stolz-Cesaro and other tricks and I still can't get a solution.

Comment: The limit $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\log n)^a/( n^b)$ for $a>0, b>0$ is pretty standard and can be found in most calculus text books.

Comment: What about the behavior of $\frac{\log n}{n}$ as $n\to \infty$?  Can you make a substitution to reduce consideration to that case?

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{t\to +\infty} t\, e^{-t/2} = 0.$$

Comment: i dont understand the difference why $\lim_{t to \infty} te^{-t/2} = 0$ is obvious but not $\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln x}{x} = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\log n^{1/4} < n^{1/4} \Rightarrow \log n < 4n^{1/4} \Rightarrow \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}} < \frac{4}{\sqrt[4]{n}}  $$

Take $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I have fixed a minor typo. You should have $\sqrt[4]{n}$ instead of $\sqrt{n}$ in the last.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks, I thought I had written it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use L'Hopital's rule?

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\text{log}(n)/n^{\frac{1}{2}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{2n^{1/2}}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2n^{1/2}}=0
\end{equation}

Comment: It's on the tag, the reason.

Comment: Um, can we use this? $n$ is a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

The fact you should remember is that $\log$ function will be bitten by any positive order of $x$, i.e., $x^\alpha$ for any $\alpha>0$. In another word, for any $\alpha>0$, $x^\alpha$ will growth faster then $\log x$ at infinity. Hence, the limit of you problem is $0$.

Comment: It is better to prove the result that "$\log$ will be bitten by any positive order of $x$". A very nice proof is given by Aaron Maroja in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\log n\over\sqrt x}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{1/x\over \frac12x^{-1/2}}$$

by L'hopital
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{1/x\over \frac12x^{-1/2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{\sqrt x}=0.$$